# jackson deserialization of json with a numbered array

Tags: java, arrays, json, list, jackson

I have a JSON string like this:

```
{
  "1": {
    "entity_id":"1",
    "status":"canceled"
  },
  "2": {
    "entity_id":"2",
    "status":"pending"
  }
}
```

I am struggling to find the correct settings to use when deserializing this. I stumble on what looks like mapping the `"1"` and `"2"` id's in the above.

My object mapper looks like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING, true);
mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
```

I've tried all sorts of classes to map it to, but none of them have worked when using the following line:

```
XXX jsonObject = mapper.readValue(json, XXX.class);
```

Any suggestions on what the `XXX` class should look like?

Comment: That's not a "numbered array", that's an "object" -- a map.

Comment: Can you do anything about the server? In such case, the server should return an array, instead of an object with number as keys.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant change the server's response at all. Its a 3rd party integration.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction. I am now using this line to deserialize the json:

Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(message, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to map the json into a map as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(message, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

In the actual code I replaced Object with a java class that maps the fields such as entity_id and status